# createQueryBuilder condition oneToMany

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.4 And I have a problem with a query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->leftJoin('o.prices', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.dateEnd >= :now OR p.dateEnd IS NULL')
    ->setParameter('now', $nowDate);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So, I have an entity `Offer o` **OneToMany** `Price p`.

I need with this query get offers and price only if the condition is valid : `p.dateEnd >= :now OR p.dateEnd IS NULL`

I have in my database 2 prices with dateEnd=null and dateEnd=2018-01-01 00:00:00, So I expecte to retrieve only the price with dateEnd=null but I have all prices in my getResult()...

Why ?

How can I get only a specific price and not all prices for each offers?

Thanks!

Edit: This is my sql:

```sql
SELECT o0_.id AS id_0
FROM offer o0_
  LEFT JOIN price p1_
    ON o0_.id = p1_.offerId
      AND (p1_.date_end >= ? OR p1_.date_end IS NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Print the dql created, It could be an help

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Is it `dateEnd` or `date_end`? You are talking about the former but the SQL uses the latter.

Comment: can you please show your records please?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: what is the value of $nowDate ?

Comment: Tried with new \DateTime(), new \DateTime('now') or directly CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: try with a simple 
$nowDate = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');

Comment: The same ^^ If I try the query directly in phpmyadmin it's ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer fo this is to add `->select('o', 'p')` to the query.. Don't know why !

Comment: leftJoin does the join, that may be enough in order to filter some data. But if you also want to get them after hydrataion, you have to tell it to Doctrine. You could add `->addSelect('p')`, it's sufficient (root entity is selected by default).

Answer (score 0):

As it's a left join, I think you could write your query like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->leftJoin('o.prices', 'p')
        ->where('p.dateEnd >= :now OR p.dateEnd IS NULL')
        ->setParameter('now', $nowDate);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: It's the same ;)

Comment: It's less efficient from MySQL point of view. Put the condition on the clause directly eliminates non-matching prices, before the WHERE clause is applied.

Comment: I just wanted to know if my solution was also working or not, even if yours is better ^^